# Append Once jQuery Onscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension that adds a button to https://www.fashionnova.com/ items.

[image]

I'd like to only append my button once, but when I used an if statement my button did not appear. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function ($) {
  var button = CreateButton();

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    className = ".product-tile__badges";
    console.log($(className).children()[1].className);
    console.log("i work");
    $(className).append(button);

    $(".product-tile__badges").mouseenter(function () {
      button.childNodes[1].style.display = "block"; // Makes the dropdown appear
    });

    $(".product-tile__badges").mouseleave(function () {
      button.childNodes[1].style.display = "none"; // Makes the dropdown appear
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery's unbind](https://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove the scroll event listener once the button has been appended.

That would give something like:

```js
jQuery("document").ready(function ($) {
  var button = CreateButton();

  function injectButton() {
   var className = ".product-tile__badges";

   // append button
   $(className).append(button);

   // add event listener to show dropdown on mouse enter
   $(className).mouseenter(function () {
     button.childNodes[1].style.display = "block";
   });

   // add event listener to hide dropdown on mouse leave
   $(className).mouseleave(function () {
     button.childNodes[1].style.display = "none";
   });

   // remove handler from window scroll event listenenr
   $(window).unbind('scroll', injectButton);
  }

  // attach the event handler on window scroll
  $(window).scroll(injectButton);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It appears on the first 3-4 rows.  Any suggestion on how to grab all of the "product-tile__badges" at once? I am playing with a timer now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "grab". If you want to select all elements with that class using jQuery, you can do: `$(".product-tile__badges")`